# Trouble matching SRTM data clip to slippy tile extents

Tags: clip, gdal-translate, srtm

I'm trying to extract the SRTM data for some slippy tile in QGIS, and it doesn't seem clipping to the right extents.

Here are some of the data for the tiles that I'm using to test (this data comes from a python program I wrote that uses the math and code from OSM's wiki described [here](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Slippy_map_tilenames)) :

```
tileX: 710 tileY: 1618 zoom: 12

(xmin,xmax,ymin,ymax) -117.59765625 , -117.509765625 , 35.24561909420682 , 35.31736632923787

tileX: 710 tileY: 1619 zoom: 12

(xmin,xmax,ymin,ymax) -117.59765625 , -117.509765625 , 35.17380831799958 , 35.24561909420682

tileX: 711 tileY: 1618 zoom: 12

(xmin,xmax,ymin,ymax) -117.509765625 , -117.421875 , 35.24561909420682 , 35.31736632923787

tileX: 711 tileY: 1619 zoom: 12

(xmin,xmax,ymin,ymax) -117.509765625 , -117.421875 , 35.17380831799958 , 35.24561909420682
```

The trouble I'm having is that as the data above clearly shows the tiles should form a perfect square, but when I run the conversion in QGIS (as shown below), there is a one-pixel space in between each of the tiles.  I hadn't touched the SRTM data at all besides combining some SRTM tiles (although this happened before when I didn't combine them).

An example of what gdal_translate call that QGIS is using is this (in this case it generates the clip of the top left tile shown below):

```
gdal_translate -projwin -117.59765625 35.31736632923787 -117.509765625 35.24561909420682 -of GTiff C:/Users/MyName/AppData/Local/Temp/processing_ae12691e47564eee9da900e8b6630ef7/7915b60331804d34b1cc3bbd7090bc16/OUTPUT.tif C:/Users/MyName/AppData/Local/Temp/processing_ae12691e47564eee9da900e8b6630ef7/286195c76a1047d897385114a284dba2/OUTPUT.tif
```

Does anyone know what the cause of this space is?

[image: Qgis screenshot]